# Adjust height of subplot with 1 row and 2 columns

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to create two plots, with the second plot generally being about 1/2 or less the size of the main plot. However, when trying to do this with one row and two columns I get an error

```
fig, axs=plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,10), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [2,1],
                                                        'width_ratios':[3,1]})
```

(`ValueError: Expected the given number of height ratios to match the number of rows of the grid`).

If I only put in one argument in the list for `height ratios` then I get two plots that are of the same size.

```
fig, axs=plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,10), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3],
                                                        'width_ratios':[3,1]})
```

That plot is shown below. How can I make the plot on the right half the size of the one on the left, while placing it in the bottom right (not top right)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that `height_ratios` depends on the number of rows. A ratio is a relationship between 2 things so you cannot introduce a ratio between height subplots if there is only one row (aka one 'height' for the subplots) - no matter how many columns there are. However, you can trick `plt.subplots` using `fig.add_gridspec` to introduce more rows and columns but never call on them. Here is how you can go about it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__":

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
    gs = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=2, ncols=2, width_ratios=[3, 1])

    fig.suptitle('An overall title')

    # Add left subplot
    # gs[top and bottom rows, first column (the 'left' subplot))]
    ax_left = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 0])
    ax_left.set_xlabel("Left X label")
    ax_left.set_ylabel("Left Y label")

    # Add bottom right subplot - gs[bottom row, last column (the 'left' subplot)]
    # We do not add the upper right subplot
    ax_right_bottom = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1, -1])
    ax_right_bottom.set_xlabel("Right Bottom X label")
    ax_right_bottom.set_ylabel("Right Bottom Y label")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image: A gridspec example]

If you wanted to make the bottom right subplot smaller or bigger in relation to the left subplot, now you could use `height_ratios` because now there are two rows and you can implement a ratio.

You can read more about it in [Arranging multiple Axes in a Figure](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/arranging_axes.html) - it's full of useful tips for wrangling axes and subplots. Cheers!